# Question mark and no internet access

Tags: unix

Suddenly, out of the blue, my internet is not working at all, I’ve tried all I found on the internet but in vain. I think is a dns problem or I don’t know. The problem occurred after I tried to switch the network one time( i mean connect to a different wlan, even by cable). I m really confused, I m new to Linux

Comment: "I’ve tried all I found on the internet but in vain" – what exactly? What distribution? Any logs? specific errors? screenshots? Please [edit] the question and specify the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried to switch the network"? Please add to your question details of what you did and what you were trying to do.

Comment: i have editted it @AFH

Comment: it was from firewall, i had outgoing on deny, dude .. i m so sorry i ve figured it out just now

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Check if network is connected and IP is showing for the system

```
    ifconfig -a
```

Step 2. Check if default gateway is showing for the system.

```
    netstat -nr | grep -i default
```

Step 3. Whether gateway is pinging (assuming 10.10.1.1 is gateway in step 2).

```
    ping 10.10.1.1
```

Step 4. Whether DNS is reachable (test for google dns)

```
    ping 8.8.8.8
```

Step 5. Whether DNS is working

```
    nslookup www.google.com
```

Step 6. You can share the outputs of above steps which will help in finding the issues.